# A função do control não atinge os textbox do TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms

Fiz uma função usando o evento `PreviewKeyDown` para que quando fosse apertado uma tecla, nesse caso **TAB** passaria um `foreach` em todos os casos onde existisse um TextBox, porém, essa função não atinge os TextBox que estão dentro das TabPage que por sua vez, dentro de um TabControl.

```
private void tb_id_prod_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Tab && tb_id_prod.Text == "0")
            {
                foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
                {
                    if (c.GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox")
                    {
                        c.Text = String.Empty;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde está circulado de vermelho, a função apaga o que tem no texto, porém, onde está em preto não apaga.

Alguém sabe o que possa estar ocorrendo?

Comment: Consegui arrumar, inserir um ```foreach``` antes que passava um ```Array``` do tipo ```TabPage``` com o nome de todas as ```TabPage``` e apagando todos os campos, se algum moderador puder encerrar a question, agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque a propriedade `Controls` itera os controles apenas em primeiro nível em relação ao controle pai. Para iterar os controles dentro de outros controles você precisa usar recursão:

```cs
private void tb_id_prod_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    void AlterTextBoxes(Control ctrl) {
        foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)
        {
            if (c is System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)
            {
                c.Text = String.Empty;
            }
            AlterTextBoxes(c);
        }
    }

    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Tab && tb_id_prod.Text == "0")
    {
        AlterTextBoxes(this.Controls);
    }
}
```

Comment: Entendi, não sabia dessa informação, muito obrigado :)

Comment: @GustavoMegazorde se essa resposta te ajudou, considere marcar ela como "correta".